# what notification type do gmail use in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, push-notification

What type of notification does Gmail use in Nexus4 (Android 4.3) ?

It has two special features I would like to use as well.

a) When there are multiple mails to read all their headers appear one after the other.
and a bottom line is drawn.

[image]

b) When there is no space in the notification page, the Gmail notification shrinks and sums all headers to on line.

[image]

How do they do this? How can I do this as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically the [Big View](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html) and  [Notification.BigTextStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigTextStyle.html).

You can either customize your layout or use it under default notification by:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Message"))
                .setContentText("Message");
```

For customizing layouts of your Notifications, which may be well suited depending on the requirement, refer:
[Expandable Notifications](http://codeversed.com/expandable-notifications-android/)
[Applying Big Style](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-notifications-3-applying-big.html)